# How to use tensorflow pairwise loss

Tags: tensorflow

In tensorflow, there is a pairwise mean squared error function which takes in "predictions" it is not documented if this should be a sigmoid/softmax output or logits. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/mean_pairwise_squared_error

I am looking to see if predictions must be a certain form for the input, or if there is a better pairwise loss function available.

Answer (score 0):

The `logits` layer, in deep learning context is the layer on which the `softmax` function is applied. The `softmax` function is applied when want to perform multi-class classification. When we want to perform classification, the most common error measure is `cross-entropy`. On the other hand, the `mean pairwise squared error` is used in the context of regression. When we perform regression, we want to predict a real value as opposed to classification when we want to predict a class. With that said, the layer that will generate the outputs won't be a `logits` layer, but an ordinary linear layer. Moreover, the most common error measure when you want to perform regression is `mean squared erorr`.